# Bittorrent Clients Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 32bit

Tags: uninstall, delete, bittorrent

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu (read - noob) and am finding it very difficult to determine if there is a BT client with the "Remove Torrent, Remove + Delete Torrent, Remove + Delete Torrent + Data" options that were so handy in utorrent. All I've been able to find is people complaining about the LACK of these options (QBittorrent, Deluge, Transmission, etc.). I would appreciate the ability to remove some files from the torrent list while still keeping them on my pc, while also having the option to delete others COMPLETELY. So, my question is this:

Are there any Linux BT clients with the utorrent remove/delete options?

PS, if there aren't any like utorrent, is there another way to accomplish these tasks? Thanks in advance for any and all help/input on this matter.

Comment: I'm fairly certain transmission does this as do many if not all the others. Not at home right now but using Remote Transmission I have the ability to remove and at the same time delete data from disk.

Comment: Thank you ElefantPhace, I had actually overlooked Transmission (dumb, i know, considering it's the default), although most of what I've managed to google-fu the last day or so seems to suggest otherwise.QBitttorrent and Deluge were ranked as the top 2 in the software center, so I started with them. Also, my device is my desktop pc, no remote (again - noob). I actually did install QBittorrent, which I was quite happy with until I noticed that there was only a "delete" option. Whew! Man am I long-winded sometimes, at any rate, once again, I thank you.

Comment: Mine too, [Remote Transmission](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neogb.rtac&hl=en) is an app I use on my phone to control transmission at my home

Answer (score 0):

I use [Tixati](http://www.tixati.com/download/linux.html). It has *Remove* and *Remove and Delete Local Files* options. It is not available in the official repository, but a Debian package file is provided.

Comment: Cool, hadn't heard of this til now, good lookin-out. I'll begin testing these new waters immediately muru, tysvm!